# Batch move folder with random name

Tags: batch-file, random, directory, move, xcopy

I need to move folders and their structure to somewhere else.
I don't know the name of those folders.
Move command is denied & copy doesn't keep structure in this state :

```
    @echo on
    for /D %%b in (*) do XCOPY "%%~fb" "C:\Users\*Username*\Desktop\New files" /Y /E 
    timeout /t -1
```

This is what I get :

```
    sourcefolder                           destinationfolder
      | Randomfolder1                         | Randomfolder2
      |    |  Randomfolder2                   |    \randomfile2.txt 
      |    |     \randomfile2.txt             \randomfile1.txt
      |    \randomfile1.txt
      \moverandomfolders.bat
```

Obviously I miss the name of the new folder in its new directory to keep the same structure. How do you add that random name to the new path ?
I'd also need something to delete folders from their original path after they have been copied.

```
    rd /s /q "*random folder name*"
```

Comment: Are you just trying to copy everything to the same directory structure in the new location?  If so, you don't need to iterate the directories with `FOR`; something like `robocopy source destination /MIR /MOVE` should do it.

Comment: Your source folder will be sourcefolder\Randomfolder1 and destination will destinationfolder.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I don't want any files from source folder (root directory of my batch) being moved. But I do want random folders with random names in this root folder being moved elsewhere (on my desktop for ex.). That `FOR` will scan root and look only for folders. Again, the problem is, I can't tell what's the name of the folder (Radomfolder1) needed to be moved in (destinationfolder). So ATM I just have the content of that Randomfolder1 being copied to my destination folder. I need that Randomfolder1 to apear as is in my destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

I though making it with something like storing random folder names in vars but I made it simply work with an excludedfileslist, since I know them.

```
        @echo on
        for /D %%b in (*) do XCOPY "root folder" "destination folder" /Y /E /EXCLUDE:excludedfileslist.txt
        for /D /R "root folder" %%X IN (*) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"
        timeout /t -1
```